# Android: How to write customize array adapter for objects

Tags: android, object, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to make customize array adapter that can be used for object "data"

```
 public class theAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private ArrayList <listToDo> list;
public theAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<listToDo>list) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_layout, list);
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,parent,false);
    listToDo activity = (listToDo) getItem(position);
    TextView theTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    theTextView.setText(activity.things);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.setChecked(activity.checked);
    return view;
}
```

}

However, this prints out same thing over and over again. 
For instance if the ArrayList has 1,2,3,4,5. (this is not exact object I have)
It prints out 5,5,5,5,5.

EDIT---------------------------------

```
        protected void dataRead (){
        File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"user.txt");
        listToDo original = new listToDo ();
        try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader temp = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(temp);
        String activity;
        while ((activity = bis.readLine()) != null){
            String[] parts = activity.split("\t");
            original.things = parts[0];
            if (parts[1] == "1"){
                original.checked=true;
            }
            else{
                original.checked=false;
            }
            data.add(original);
            Log.v(TAG, original.things);
        }
            for (int i =0; i < data.size(); i++){
                Log.d(TAG,data.get(i).things);
            }
        bis.close();
    }
    catch  (Exception e) {
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation : the current way you are creating your list items only ever creates ONE listToDo named "original" and changes the values in it during each loop.  Also in the loop you add the same `original` object over again for however many lines you have in `user.txt`. So, lets move the listToDo instance creation inside your loop so it will create a new listTodo class object named `original` each loop, set some values (checked and things), and then add to the `data` List

```
protected void dataRead (){
    File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"user.txt");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader temp = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(temp);
        String activity;
        while ((activity = bis.readLine()) != null){
            listToDo original = new listToDo ();
            String[] parts = activity.split("\t");
            original.things = parts[0];
            if ("1".equals(parts[1])) {
                original.checked=true;
            }
            else{
                original.checked=false;
            }
            data.add(original);
            Log.v(TAG, original.things);
        }
        for (int i =0; i < data.size(); i++){
            Log.d(TAG,data.get(i).things);
        }
        bis.close();
    }
    catch  (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Also, I think your adapter class is a bit off.

```
public class theAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<listToDo> {

    public theAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<listToDo> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.my_layout, list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        listToDo activity = (listToDo) getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView theTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        theTextView.setText(activity.things);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(activity.checked);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is a full on tutorial just in case :
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: @Karakuri is probably right,  can you show us how you are creating the ArrayList<listToDo> list ?

Comment: @Karakuri No sir, I checked my data before I asked this question

Comment: @petey I edited on your request. Yes, I am sorry I think my creating ArrayList is the problem because. When I print out when it is reading the data. It reads correctly but after they are added to the ArrayList, and read again, they print out same ting over and over again

Comment: @petey Oh wow! it works thank you so much. May I ask why moving the instance creation inside the loop fix the problem?

Comment: @h2sk ok, I added the loop fix explanation

Comment: also, strings are compared using the `equals` method not `==`. Added that fix too.

Comment: @petey One last question, in my list view, I have unknown number of checkboxes. I need to keep track of the check boxes whether they are checked. However, I have been googling for awhile and they don't really help my situation any better. I wonder if you have a clue of it